# Apache2 VHost for subdomain

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, nextcloud, conf

I configured several months ago my nextcloud on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS VM running on my FreeNAS, following their tutorial so bear with me, I'm in no means a trained apache2 guru ;-)

My current VHost config for my nextcloud is as followed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@domain.net
     DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud/
     ServerName cloud.domain.net
     ServerAlias www.cloud.domain.net

     Alias /nextcloud "/var/www/nextcloud/"

     <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
          <IfModule mod_dav.c>
            Dav off
          </IfModule>
        SetEnv HOME /var/www/nextcloud
        SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/nextcloud
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =cloud.domain.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.cloud.domain.net
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I recently set up my Home Assistant and wanted to grant remote access via the HASS App.
I wanted to redirect traffic, comming in via

https://homeassistant.domain.net

My approach for the homeassistant.conf was:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName homeassistant.domain.net

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.9:8123/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.9:8123/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work....

Can anyone point me to the right config so my Home Assistant Trafic is also ssl encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your `VirtualHost` statements are exactly the same. Currently, one of them says `VirtualHost *`, and the other says `VirtualHost *:80`. This is wrong. Since it's generally a better idea to have the port number, you should add the `:80` bit to the other `VirtualHost` line. This should make it work without encryption.

In order to add HTTPS, you have more things to do. The instructions below explain what to do for your `homeassistant.domain.net` domain, but you'll have to repeat the instructions for your nextcloud domain, if you want to encrypt traffic there too.

First, you'll need a certificate. Since you're saying you want to "grant remote access", I'm assuming your server is available from the public Internet; that means you can use [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org):

1. Install `certbot`, letsencrypt's application to create and install certificates.
2. Modify your `VirtualHost` stanza so it doesn't proxy the "/.well-known" directory, and give it a DocumentRoot, by adding the following lines

   ```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/homeassistant
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
   ```
3. Create the `/var/www/homeassistant` directory, if it doesn't exist yet.
4. Run certbot to create your certificates:

   ```
    certbot register
    certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/homeassistant -d homeassistant.domain.net
   ```

   The first of these commands will register you with letsencrypt; the second will request a certificate that it will install into `/etc/letsencrypt`.

   Note: certbot also has a mode to automagically enable SSL and install the certificates for you, but I have never used it and so don't know what exactly it does. You might want to play with it. In order to do so, use --apache rather than --webroot, and read the `certbot --help` output. The rest of this post assums you *didn't* do that, and instead used the `--webroot` mode.
5. Ensure `certbot renew` is run periodically, so that your certificates are automatically renewed before they expire (e.g., by using `cron`).

You now have certificates under /etc/letsencrypt. In order to enable SSL and use them, you need to take the following steps:

1. Ensure that `mod_ssl` is loaded; if you use Debian (or one of its derivatives, like Ubuntu) this can be done by way of `a2enmod ssl`; other systems usually have an optional configuration file or some such that you'll need to include.
2. Change every `VirtualHost` statement so it says `VirtualHost *:443`, for the HTTPS port.
3. add the required options for SSL to your `VirtualHost` stanzas:

   ```
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/homeassistant.domain.net/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/homeassistant.domain.net/privkey.pem
   ```
4. (optionally) add a redirecting stanza so that plain HTTP requests 80 get redirected to HTTPS:

   ```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName homeassistant.domain.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/homeassistant
        <Directory /var/www/homeassistant>
            Require all granted
            Redirect permanent / https://homeassistant.domain.net/
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
   ```

   This requires `mod_alias`, which is usually enabled (but you may have to enable it if not; on Debian and derivatives, you'd use `a2enmod alias`).
5. (optionally) harden your SSL configuration by using Strict-Transport-Security, and a few other options:

   ```
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000
    Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
   ```

   This requires `mod_headers` (`a2enmod headers`).

Comment: Hey Wouter,thanks for the answer - the hint with the port number was great. I searched further and noticed I had to add some configuration to my Home Assistant (see this: https://community.home-assistant.io/t/home-assistant-400-bad-request-docker-proxy-solution/322163)

I got Http acces now working but with the SSL Certificate I got some problem to solve.

I get an Invalid Response of certbot...

  `Domain: homeassistant.domain.net`
   `Type:   unauthorized`
   `Detail: Invalid response from`
   `http://homeassistant.domain.net/.well-known/acme-challenge`
   `[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]: 404`

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changing the configuration file? That's necessary; Apache won't automatically reread the configuration file. If you did, please see if you find something interesting in your error logs...